# Excel VBA - Split text using " delimiter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string of text on witch I need to split it using the symbol " as a delimiter. The problem I'm facing is than the "Split" function does not accept " as a delimiter by itself.

Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: `Split(var, chr(34))`

Comment: @braX I've tried, but it does not work...

Comment: @MiguelGutiérrezdeAntón What is your data and where it is saved? In cell on in a variable in code module?

Comment: The data is on a string, and is a HTML request (something like: "{ value :[{ employeeId : 112382926 , employeeLogin : xxx,....)

Comment: I see no `"` in that data sample ...

Comment: _I've tried, but it does not work_. It does, but it seems like you don't have any `"` in your data to split.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `Hello"Excel` in cell `A1` then try below sub.

```
Sub MySplit()
Dim x As String

    x = Range("A1")
    MsgBox Split(x, Chr(34))(1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you say is just not true.

```
A = "Cat*Dog"
B = Split(A, """")
For each thingy in B
    Msgbox thingy
Next
```

Comment: OP's delimeter is `"` double quote not `*` asterisk.

Comment: Just change the delimiter. Remember strings start and end with odd number of quotes. Quotes in strings are in even numbers. So 1 + 2 + 1 = 4.

Comment: This answer is not useful as what OP has asked is something else